# Find the linearization of the function at 0

Tags: approximation

The problem asks: Find the linearization of $f(x)= \sqrt{a+bx} $ at $0$

To get all parts of $L(x) \approx f(c) - f'(c)(x-c)$

I've done:

$$f(0) = \sqrt{a}$$
 $$f'(0) = {b\over 2\sqrt{a}} $$

Now:
 $$L \approx \sqrt{a} + {b\over 2\sqrt{a}}(x-0)$$
 $$= \sqrt{a} + {bx\over 2\sqrt{a}}$$

If I plug in $0$ I'm left with $\sqrt{a}$   however, I'm getting the wrong answer. What have I done wrong?

[Link to screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SPTTG.png)

Comment: I don't understand your question; $f(0) = \sqrt{a}$ is correct.

Comment: @T.Bongers what about it don't you understand? When I saw this I wasn't sure what "find the linearization of f(x) at zero" meant so I googled it and it looked like I had to use linear approximation, which is what I've tried here, but when I plug in my answer, it tells me I am wrong.

Comment: @FakeBrain I'm with Bongers on this one

Comment: I have added a picture

Comment: @FakeBrain What tells you that you are wrong?

Comment: @T.Bongers I have added a screen shot...

Comment: @FakeBrain Becuase the linearization, as you said in your question, is $L(x) = \sqrt{a} + (b/2\sqrt{a}) x$. Not $\sqrt{a}$.

Comment: ...oh boy I am a silly person :(